# How to reference lex or parse parameters in flex rules?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I know I can declare `%parse-param {struct my_st *arg}` in a `.y` file. And so `yyparse()` is changed to be `yyparse(struct my_st *arg)`. But how do I reference the argument in the flex rules? For example:

```
[0-9]+  { do_work(arg); return NUMBER; }
```

I want to make a reentrant parser, so I need to do this. Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to pass the argument through to `yylex`. That requires a modification of both the bison parser description, so that the parser calls `yylex` with the desired arguments, and the flex scanner description, so that the scanner generates `yylex` with the desired parameters.

Bison and flex do not communicate with each other and do not see each other's source files. However, it is normal for the scanner to `#include` the header file generated by bison, and bison allows the possibility of inserting code directly into this header file. That makes it possible to put the entire configuration into the bison file.

In bison, you specify additional parameters for `yylex` using the [`%lex-param` directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Pure-Calling). But you need to be aware of the additional argument(s) which would also be added to the call if you [`%define api.pure`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Pure-Decl).

If you use bison 3.0 or more recent, you can use

```
%param { struct my_st *arg }
```

as an abbreviation for

```
%lex-param { struct my_st *arg }
%parse-param { struct my_st *arg }
```

It makes sense to use a single directive (if your bison is sufficiently recent) because there is no way to insert a local variable declaration into the `yyparse` function. So the only variables which could be passed through to `yylex` are global variables and parameters to `yyparse`. [Note 1]

Remember that it is your responsibility to declare `yylex` and `yyerror` in the bison file. Even if you use `%lex-param`, bison will not automatically generate a declaration for `yylex`. [Note 2]

Flex does normally generate a declaration for `yylex`, so you cannot simply put your declaration into the bison-generated header file and then `#include` it into the scanner. However, if the [`YY_DECL` macro](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Generated-Scanner.html) is defined, then the flex-generated scanner will not forward-declare `yylex`, and it will use the `YY_DECL` macro in the definition of `yylex`. You can use this feature to put the declaration of `yylex` into the bison description in a way that it will be passed through to the flex scanner.

Note that this is *not* compatible with the use of `%bison-bridge`, which is often used to modify the prototype of `yylex` to work with a reentrant parser. `%bison-bridge` is certainly useful, but it does not allow adding more parameters to the `yylex` call. If you want to use `%bison-bridge`, your only option is to add the additional parameter(s) to the ["extra data" object in the `yyscan_t` object](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Extra-Data.html#Extra-Data).

In bison, you can [add declarations to the generated header](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#g_t_0025code-Summary) using either `%code requires` sections or `%code provides` sections. The difference is that `requires` segments are earlier in the header file, before `YYSTYPE` and `YYLTYPE` have been declared. If you use a pure parser, the `yylex` prototype will usually refer to `YYSTYPE` (and `YYLTYPE`, if you use locations), so it needs to go in a `%code provides` section. In order to interface gracefully with flex, you can use the `YY_DECL` macro to generate the `yylex` declaration.

So you might end up with something like the following: [Note 3]

**file: mylanguage.y**

```
%code requires {
  #include <stdio.h>

  typedef struct Context { ... } Context;

  /* structs used in the %union declaration would go here */
}

%define api.pure full
%locations
%parse-param { Context* context }
%lex-param { Context* context }

%code provides {
   #define YY_DECL \
       int yylex(YYSTYPE* yylvalp, YYLTYPE* yyllocp, Context* context)
   YY_DECL;

   int yyerror(YYLTYPE* yyllocp, Context* context, const char* message);
}
```

Then you would just insert the generated header into your flex file in the normal way:

**file: mylanguage.l**

```
%{
   /* System library includes */
   #include "mylanguage.tab.h"
%}
```

The `%define api.pure full` declaration in bison avoids the need for the global variables `yylval` and `yylloc`. However, there are a number of other internal globals used by a flex-generated scanner; in order to make the scanner truly re-entrant, you need to add `%option reentrant` to your flex file. With that option, `yylex` is expected to include the parameter `yyscan_t yyscanner` (as are all the other lexer-related functions defined by flex). You need to manage the `yyscanner` value, so it will need to be passed through `yyparse` to `yylex` as above. You also need to initialize and destroy it, as described in the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Reentrant-Overview.html). (Its name in `yylex` must be precisely `yyscanner`, if you are generating the `yylex` prototype using `YY_DECL`.)

If you also want to pass your own context object, you could add two parameters to `yyparse` and `yylex`, or you could include your context object inside the `yyscan_t` object as described in the Flex manual [section on Extra Data](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Extra-Data.html).

Finally, if you use the bison pure parser API, then you need to change the way you write flex actions. Instead of assigning to the global `yylval` (eg. `yylval.integer = atol(yytext);`), you need to assign through the pointer passed as an argument: `yylvalp->integer = atol(yytext);`. (The name of the argument is up to you; the one I use here is the one I specified above.)

---

#### Notes

1. Older implementations allowed you to specify the arguments to `yylex` by defining the macro `YYLEX_PARAM`. This is no longer supported as of bison 3.0, so you shouldn't use it.
2. If you use `%parse-param`, the additional parameter will also be added to `yyerror`. And if you `%define api-pure full`, `yyerror` will also receive a location object. Your declaration of `yyerror` needs to be consistent.
3. The `%locations` directive forces bison to generate code which stores location information for each token. I use it here because it makes the prototypes predictable. Without it, the prototypes would include `YYLTYPE` arguments only if you actually refer to a location somewhere in a semantic action. If you don't intend to use token locations, you might prefer to remove the `%locations` directive and all the `YYLTYPE` arguments. But usually the location information is useful.

Comment: It's very helpful for me! And I find an example project that is very likely with your answer! Here is the project: [https://github.com/blynn/symple/tree/master](https://github.com/blynn/symple/tree/master)

Comment: The `%code provides {}` part is not working on my macbook. While the `Context *context` parameter is correct in `int yyparse(Context *context)`, the yylex remains the `int yylex(YYSTYPE *yylval, YYLTYPE *yylloc, yyscan_t yyscanner)`. Then yyparse parse `context` to yylex as the 3rd parameter, parser will fail because the error that `context` pointer is used as `yyscanner` by yylex.

Comment: In @PengQu's example, in bison file defines something like: `%parse-param { yyscan_t yyscanner } %parse-param { Context *context } %lex-param { yyscan_t yyscanner }`, which will generate `int yyparse(yyscan_t yyscanner, Context *context)` and `int yylex(YYSTYPE *yylval, YYLTYPE *yylloc, yyscan_t yyscanner)`, that really works!

Comment: @linrongbin: are you using `%bison-brudge`?

Comment: @rici, I use `%bison-bridge`, here's my repo: https://github.com/coli-lang/coli, check `Token.l` and `Parser.y`

Comment: @linrongbin: `%bison-bridge` is incompatible with using `YY_DECL` to modify the `yylex` prototype. I edited the answer to mention that, which I should have done when I wrote it. `%bison-bridge` does not allow you to add more parameters; if you want to use `YY_DECL` to do that, as this answer suggests,  you cannot use %bison-bridge. But why do you want that? You can pass an arbitrary object into the flex scanner using extra-data, as indicated in the second last paragraph of the answer (and now in a paragraph higher up, as well.)

Comment: @linrongbin: Also, I did take a glance at your repository but I don't see the point of your `Scanner` object; it seems to be just duplicating data already stored in the `yyscan_t` object (and which are therefore accessible from your bison code already).

Comment: @rici Scanner is in ‘Token.h’, it’s the context in my project, I need to access my scanner in bison, so I simply make it a parameter in yyparse function, and yes it’s duplicate with yyextra.

Comment: @rici emmmmm, I have no idea that if I can use yyextra in bison. I will try it, if so, it will be much more convenience to use yyextra to get my context, instead of add another duplicating Scanner parameter.

Comment: @linrongbin: You get the value of the extra data object using `YY_EXTRA_TYPE yyget_extra ( yyscan_t yyscanner );`. You can certainly do that from your parser since your parser is passed `yyscanner` as a parameter. You only need the declaration for `yyget_extra`; you'll find it in the header generated by flex, if you ask for one, but use that header with caution: it has no header guard and must not be included in the C file generated by flex (since it is already there). If you run into problems trying to include the flex header file, just use the prototype from this comment.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's the best solution.

Comment: Wish I found this solution 8 days ago! Upvoting to spread the knowledge, I'm also going to write an article on this whole mess for beginners to skim and understand. I'll make sure to credit you!